# RethinkDB: OpsWorks

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm interested in using [RethinkDB](http://rethinkdb.com) as an OpsWorks Layer in my existing Stack but I'm having trouble getting my cookbooks to work. If someone has a cookbook repo they could share, or any pointers that would be fantastic.

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Recipes used (Git submodules in my cookbook repo)

  - https://github.com/AVVSDevelopment/chef-rethinkdb
  - https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt

I added rethink and rethink::start to the setup phase of the layer, but when it runs it can't find apt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of digging, I was able to sort out many of the differences between OpsWorks Chef and official Chef releases. I've included all OpsWorks cookbooks and trimmed the RethinkDB on down to the basics. Now it works and I just have cleanup / replication. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error message you're getting?

One thing I see in the recipe is that the RethinkDB version is set to 1.7.1. The current version is 1.11.3 -- I'd try to set that in the recipe.

Comment: I've been modifying the cookbook bit by bit here: https://github.com/sumoheavy/opsworks-cookbooks, and I've got it down to this: "I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!"

Comment: Check out https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Common+Errors -- inability to read client.pem is in their FAQ.